# leader based shortcut to vim grep content in " register

Tags: vimgrep

I would like to do a  vimgrep shortcut where I am able to place the contents of the register, ", as string input, something like:

```
noremap <leader>s :vim /<something here that could always paste the register content of "/ **/*.c <CR>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<c-r>` can be used on the command-line to insert the contents of a register. `<c-r>/` will insert the contents of the current `"/` register. e.g.

```
noremap <leader>s :vim /<c-r>// **/*.c <cr>
```

It is also a good idea to supply a mode. Normal mode makes sense here. For maintenance purposes it is also best to use full names instead of shortcuts:

```
nnoremap <leader>s :vimgrep /<c-r>// **/*.c<cr>
```

Since this likely is only useful in a c files, it might be best to set this only for `'filetype'` is `c` and use `<buffer>` option to make it local to that buffer either file a ftplugin or an `FileType` `:autocmd` event

Comment: Could you explain what  <c-r>/ is doing is this Ctrl and / register?

Comment: Ctrl+r is `<c-r>` so `<c-r>/` is Ctrl+r followed by `/` to insert the `"/` register. See `:h key-notation` and `c_CTRL-R` for more help

Comment: Thanks, it works